# How do I send a custom variable with paypal standard integration checkout?

Tags: mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to use IPN to update the user's 'payment status' in my MySQL table once the user has paid.

I am using PayPal's standard integration checkout. After doing some reading, I figured out that I need to send a custom variable containing the user's MySQL table id to PayPal in order for PayPal to post it to the IPN once the user has paid. Then, I can retrieve the MySQL entry using the user's id and update the 'payment status' to paid.

I have been able to do everything stated above except send the custom variable with PayPal's standard integration checkout. I know the code to send the custom variable goes something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='custom' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
```

In the above code, $id is the user's id from the MySQL table that I have put in a php variable.

My question is, where do I include this code? Here is the standard integration checkout code that PayPal gave me to paste into my browser (with the exception of my client id, for obvious reasons).

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=my_client_id">
</script>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<!-- Add the checkout buttons, set up the order and approve the order -->
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
               createOrder: function(data, actions) {
               return actions.order.create({
                                           purchase_units: [{
                                           amount: {
                                           value: '29.99'
                                           }
                                           }]
                                           });
               },
               onApprove: function(data, actions) {
               return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                                                   alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                                                   });
               }
               }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Display payment options on your web page
</script>
```

EDIT:

I figured out that this process is easier using PayPal's basic integration setup, and that I can use the purchase_units variable "custom_id". However, I'd like to make custom id a javascript variable that I define earlier in the document, like so:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=my_client_id&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'white',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',

      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '29.99'
                  }
          custom_id: {
              value: id
          }
              }],
          application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
              }
          });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

But this doesn't work:(. In fact, I cannot get the custom_id variable to work at all. Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
// send value from payment form
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom; ?>" />

// receive on ipn page from paypal
   $custom = $_POST['custom'];
```